# MAC CodePoint in Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, unicode, codepages

When I examine different code pages on Windows OS, there is a code point named "MAC-CP" stands for default Macintosh code page,

```
> (Get-WinSystemLocale).TextInfo 

ANSICodePage   : 1254
OEMCodePage    : 857
MacCodePage    : 10081
EBCDICCodePage : 20905
LCID           : 1055
CultureName    : en-US
IsReadOnly     : False
ListSeparator  : ;
IsRightToLeft  : False
```

I heard that Macintosh cp usage is very rare. However, I wonder **when I may need** this character set, what kind of things will be affected by the current operating system I changed it to?

Comment: You would need this codepage if you have data encoded as a Turkish Mac codepage 10081 file. Do you have a problem with source code involved? Is there something that is not working?

Comment: No ı don't have any issue for this, and also I don't have any mac notebook to test it, when I check it on my codepoints, I saw it in the output. I made some research about mac cp but I couldnt find any good example or explanation for this. @lit

Comment: [Each locale has 4 different default associated code pages: OEM (DOS), ANSI (Windows), EBCDIC and Mac (classic) code pages](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72143879/995714), likely for interoperation before the era of Unicode

Comment: EBCDIC is for IBM so it has nothing to do with Windows either

Comment: @phuclv, thank u but in addition, I need some couple of examples

Comment: Of what do you need an example? Are you wanting a Turkish Mac codepage 10081 text file? Do you seek source code that will read a Turkish Mac codepage 10081 file on any machine? What problem needs to be solved? If there is not a problem to be solved, SO people might think this question to be off-topic according to https://stackoverflow.com/help. dewa mata

Comment: Yes, sounds like that, for example is the "codepage 10081" different meaning on any MAC or IBM? So, what kind of things will be affected by the current operating system I changed it to? @lit

Comment: What about the current operating system are you talking about changing? A file using "codepage 10081" is the same on every system. It is just a file.

Comment: My current operating system Windows, so MACCP is point to Macintosh characters, so why we need to MACCP, if they are already same?